# Ordering an Array of Dates from most recent to oldest whilst changing the other arrays to match the order

Tags: arrays, swift, date

I have an array of dates to go along with two other arrays of strings. I'm trying to figure out how to reorder the array of Dates from most recent to oldest. Also, when changing the order of the Date Array the two other arrays need to change to the same order as the Date Arrays.

**Here are the arrays**

```
[2019-01-15 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-07 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-22 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-09 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-06 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-28 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-18 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-31 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-14 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-20 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-16 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-30 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-20 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-29 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-15 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-14 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-19 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-30 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-04 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-14 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-22 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-06 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-22 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-19 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-05 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-28 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-23 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-16 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-05 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-31 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-01 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-18 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-06 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-17 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-16 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-09 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-01 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-07 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-29 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-17 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-18 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-19 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-23 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-04 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-23 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-05 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-04 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-17 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-10 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-28 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-29 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-07 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-30 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-31 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-20 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-10 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-10 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-01 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-09 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-15 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-15 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-07 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-22 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-09 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-06 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-28 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-18 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-31 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-14 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-20 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-16 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-30 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-20 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-29 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-15 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-14 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-19 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-30 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-04 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-14 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-22 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-06 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-22 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-19 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-05 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-28 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-23 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-16 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-05 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-31 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-01 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-18 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-06 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-17 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-16 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-09 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-08 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-01 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-07 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-29 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-17 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-25 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-18 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-19 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-23 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-04 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-23 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-05 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-24 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-04 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-17 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-10 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-28 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-29 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-07 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-30 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-11 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-31 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-20 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-10 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-10 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-02-01 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-09 05:00:00 +0000, 2018-12-21 05:00:00 +0000, 2019-01-15 05:00:00 +0000]

["5.2 hrs", "5.02 hrs", "5.77 hrs", "6.72 hrs", "5.88 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "6.08 hrs", "6.93 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.6 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "5.88 hrs", "6.27 hrs", "6.32 hrs", "4.52 hrs", "5.2 hrs", "6.13 hrs", "6.38 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "5.88 hrs", "6.13 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.25 hrs", "6.07 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "7.2 hrs", "6.27 hrs", "5.77 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.0 hrs", "5.77 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "6.37 hrs", "6.93 hrs", "6.25 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "3.17 hrs", "4.52 hrs", "6.0 hrs", "6.8 hrs", "7.2 hrs", "6.6 hrs", "6.37 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.93 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "6.08 hrs", "6.38 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.18 hrs", "6.6 hrs", "7.2 hrs", "4.52 hrs", "6.72 hrs", "6.25 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "5.02 hrs", "6.32 hrs", "6.18 hrs", "6.13 hrs", "6.08 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "3.17 hrs", "6.07 hrs", "3.17 hrs", "6.37 hrs", "6.0 hrs", "6.07 hrs", "6.18 hrs", "6.55 hrs", "6.8 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "6.8 hrs", "6.32 hrs", "5.02 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.38 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.55 hrs", "6.55 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "6.72 hrs", "6.27 hrs", "5.2 hrs", "5.2 hrs", "5.02 hrs", "5.77 hrs", "6.72 hrs", "5.88 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "6.08 hrs", "6.93 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.6 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "5.88 hrs", "6.27 hrs", "6.32 hrs", "4.52 hrs", "5.2 hrs", "6.13 hrs", "6.38 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "5.88 hrs", "6.13 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.25 hrs", "6.07 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "7.2 hrs", "6.27 hrs", "5.77 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.0 hrs", "5.77 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "6.37 hrs", "6.93 hrs", "6.25 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "3.17 hrs", "4.52 hrs", "6.0 hrs", "6.8 hrs", "7.2 hrs", "6.6 hrs", "6.37 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.93 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "6.08 hrs", "6.38 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.18 hrs", "6.6 hrs", "7.2 hrs", "4.52 hrs", "6.72 hrs", "6.25 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "5.02 hrs", "6.32 hrs", "6.18 hrs", "6.13 hrs", "6.08 hrs", "6.92 hrs", "3.17 hrs", "6.07 hrs", "3.17 hrs", "6.37 hrs", "6.0 hrs", "6.07 hrs", "6.18 hrs", "6.55 hrs", "6.8 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "6.8 hrs", "6.32 hrs", "5.02 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.38 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.75 hrs", "6.55 hrs", "6.55 hrs", "6.42 hrs", "6.72 hrs", "6.27 hrs", "5.2 hrs"]

["06:45 AM", "05:33 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:19 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:41 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:45 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:20 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:45 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:41 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:45 AM", "07:24 AM", "07:20 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:41 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:20 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:19 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "05:33 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "06:45 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:24 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:24 AM", "07:00 AM", "05:33 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:19 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:45 AM", "06:45 AM", "05:33 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:19 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:41 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:45 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:20 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:45 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:41 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:45 AM", "07:24 AM", "07:20 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:41 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:20 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:19 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "05:33 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "06:45 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:24 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:24 AM", "07:00 AM", "05:33 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:50 AM", "07:19 AM", "07:10 AM", "06:45 AM"]
```

**Day Class**

```
class Day {
    var date: Date
    var sleep: String
    var timeUploaded: String

    init(date: Date, sleep: String, timeUploaded: String) {
        self.date = date
        self.sleep = sleep
        self.timeUploaded = timeUploaded
    }
}
```

**Here is the code to read the data from firebase and put it into an object**

```
var days = [Day]()
    var dates: [Date] = []
    var sleeps: [String]  = []
    var timeUploadeds: [String] = []


    func readSleepAnalysis(){
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        self.ref.child("Patient").child(userID!).child("Sleep Analysis").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let days = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            for (_,value) in days.enumerated() {
                guard let dayDict = value.value as? [String: String] else { return }
                let date = dayDict["Date"] ?? ""
                let sleep = dayDict["Sleep"] ?? ""
                let timeUploaded = dayDict["Time Uploaded"] ?? ""



                let isoDate = date
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
                dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
                let dated = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
                let calendar = Calendar.current
                let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .year], from: dated)
                let finalDate = calendar.date(from:components)


                print(finalDate)
                let day = Day(date: finalDate!, sleep: sleep, timeUploaded: timeUploaded)
                self.days.append(day)

                self.dates.append(finalDate!)
                self.sleeps.append(sleep)
                self.timeUploadeds.append(timeUploaded)
            }
            print(days)




    }

    }
```

Comment: Any time you want to sort multiple arrays "together," you have the wrong data structure. Convert this from three arrays to one array of structs with three properties, and your problem will go away.

Comment: I made object day and created three properties to represent the three arrays that I have. I still don't know how to order the days.

Comment: You have a struct with three arrays. You want a single array of a struct with three properties: `day`, `sleep`, `timeUploaded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, the mistake is having the additional arrays (dates, sleeps, and timeUploadeds). The days array is everything you need. If you want to order it, just sort days:

```
let sortedDays = days.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date} )
```

Then you can do whatever you need with `sortedDays`. If for some specific problem you need a list of just the dates or just the sleeps, you can get that any time you need it with `map`:

```
let dates = sortedDays.map { $0.date }
```

Comment: I know that using object oriented programming is more simple. Although, I just want to be able to order the dates in one array and apply that order to the other arrays that I have.

Comment: @JohnnyMicroseed That isn't object orientation; it's data organisation and Rob is dead right about it.

Comment: I added let sortedDays = days.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date} ) . Although, I get the error back "Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no member 'date'".

Comment: You've shadowed "days." I'm talking about the `[Day]` version (`self.days`), not the array of dictionaries. I recommend against reusing the name for a property and local variable this way.